# Image inside input text

Tags: html, css

I have this desing and I´ll like to program it but I dont find the way.
Does anyone know how to make it?

[image]

How can I put that '+' inside?

Here is the piece of code:-

```css
.busqueda_input{
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    background-color: #EBE9E9;
    width: 30%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="recep-estado">
   RECEPCIÓN <hr id="hr-vertical-azul"> <input type="text" class="busqueda_input" name=""> 
   ESTADO <hr id="hr-vertical-azul"> <input type="text" class="busqueda_input" name="">
</div>
```

Comment: You can start by editing your question and adding your HTML and CSS code...

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial service, or a "Write this for me, because I don't know how..." site. [ask]

Comment: use background img or pseudo element

Comment: @radha, pseudo elements don't work on inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position:absolute`, you can literally play with css to get the required output there are many number of way for what u have asked here is something which i have made
[Example](https://codepen.io/pen/)

```css
.input-field{
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}
.input-field input{
  border:none;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 10rem;
  width:100%;
  height: 25px;
}
.icon{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: x-large;
      background: black;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10rem;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
<input type="text" >
<div class="icon">+</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
.busqueda_input{
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  background-color: #EBE9E9;
  width: 190px;
  height: 20px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.input-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.input-wrap .icon {
  background: #616261;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 29px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div class="recep-estado">
   RECEPCIÓN <hr id="hr-vertical-azul"> 
   <div class="input-wrap">
     <input type="text" class="busqueda_input" name=""> 
     <div class="icon">+</div>
   </div>
   ESTADO 
   <hr id="hr-vertical-azul"> 
   <div class="input-wrap">
     <input type="text" class="busqueda_input" name=""> 
     <div class="icon">+</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add pseudo element to the parent div
http://jsfiddle.net/w9ew0nrw/7/

```
<div class="recep-estado">
   RECEPCIÓN <hr id="hr-vertical-azul"> 
   <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="busqueda_input" name=""> 
   </div>
   ESTADO <hr id="hr-vertical-azul"> 
  <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="busqueda_input" name=""> 
   </div>
</div>

.busqueda_input{
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    background-color: #EBE9E9;
    height: 30px;
    border:0;
}
.input-group {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;

}
.input-group:after {
  position:absolute;
  top;0;
  right:0;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#333;
  color:#fff;
  content:"+";
  border-radius:0 100% 100% 0;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:
also if you want button instead of + label.

1st textbox is for  label

2nd is for  button

```css
.busqueda_input {
    border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    background-color: #EBE9E9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    display: inline-block;
        text-indent: 15px;
}

.input-div , .input-div-2 {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.input-div:after , .input-div-2 button {
    content: "+";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
    background: #616261;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}

button{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="recep-estado">
   RECEPCIÓN <hr id="hr-vertical-azul"> 
   <div class="input-div">
   <input type="text" class="busqueda_input" name="">
   </div>
   
   ESTADO <hr id="hr-vertical-azul"> <div class="input-div-2"><input type="text" class="busqueda_input" name="">
   <button>+</button>
   </div>
</div>
```